# R cbind data frames beside each other without common key

Tags: r, csv

I have two data frames with different number of rows, how can I cbind data frames beside each other without common key and then save it in a csv file separated by two empty columns. Example :

data frame 1:

```
a  b  c
1  2  3
```

data frame 2:

```
d  e  f
1  2  3
4  5  6
```

Output new data frame:

```
a  b  c  d  e  f
1  2  3  1  2  3
         4  5  6
```

CSV output:

```
a  b  c      d  e  f
1  2  3      1  2  3
             4  5  6
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `cbind.fill` from `rowr`

```
library(rowr)
cbind.fill(df1, df2, fill=NA)
#   a  b  c d e f
#1  1  2  3 1 2 3
#2 NA NA NA 4 5 6
```

Or as @RHertel mentioned in the comments

```
install.packages("qpcR")
qpcR:::cbind.na(df1,df2)
```

Comment: Do you have a solution for outputting the result to csv in the manner specified? I'm thinking one could determine where each piece came from and insert a blank column inbetween (and perhaps write it per line)?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik  No, I don't have a solution.  The `append=TRUE` I guess will work on new rows.

Comment: There's also `qpcR:::cbind.na(df1,df2)` (note the three colons).

Comment: @RHertel nice,  you could post that as a solution.  I never heard of that before.

Comment: @akrun I prefer your solution. I find it somewhat annoying that the function `cbind.na` of the `qpcR` package is not exported to the namespace and that one has to use such unusual methods to access it.

Comment: Thank you all! The solution of @akrun works. I replaced "NA" by "" as I wanted a blank space. I'm still trying to figure how to add the two empty columns in the final csv output.

Comment: @noblabla  It is not good to use `""` as it will convert the column to 'character/factor'.